# How can I handle two checkbox when clicked to enable a button in Java Android develop?

Tags: java, android

I am going to design my app in android. And I facing a problem about in a registration when I have two checkbox. When two checkbox is clicked, and the button will be enable and can be clicked to go to next activity. Here are my script.

```
private static final String TAG_Clicked = "TagClicked";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_term_signup);

    CheckBox checkBoxTOS = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_termsOfService);
    CheckBox checkBoxPNP = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_privacy_policy);
    Button buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


    checkBoxTOS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                checkBoxTOS.isChecked();
                Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"Agreed TOS "+isChecked);
            }
        }
    });
    checkBoxPNP.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                checkBoxPNP.isChecked();
                Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"Agreed PNP "+isChecked);
            }
        }
    });
    if ((checkBoxTOS.isChecked() == true) && (checkBoxPNP.isChecked() == true)){
        buttonNext.setEnabled(true);
        Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"A");
    } else {
        buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
        Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"B");
    }
}
```

Comment: `checkBoxTOS.isChecked();` That statement does nothing. You have to use something like: `if (checkBoxTOS.isChecked()){  buttonNext.setEnabled(true); else  buttonNext.setEnabled(false);}`

Comment: Or: `buttonNext.setEnabled(isChecked && checkBoxTOS.isChecked());` IN the onClick() handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check `Button` should enabled or not after check state change of both `ChecxBox`

Below code should execute after each time both checkbox check state is changed.

```
if ((checkBoxTOS.isChecked() == true) && (checkBoxPNP.isChecked() == true)){
    buttonNext.setEnabled(true);
    Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"A");
} else {
    buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
    Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"B");
}
```

Move this code in a method and call that method after CheckBox check state change

```
void changeButtonState(){
  if (checkBoxTOS.isChecked() && checkBoxPNP.isChecked() ){
      buttonNext.setEnabled(true);
      Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"A");
  } else {
      buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
      Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"B");
  }
}
```

Call this method form check change listener call back

```
checkBoxTOS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        changeButtonState();
    }
});
checkBoxPNP.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        changeButtonState();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a counter of checked boxes and manage the button state by comparing the count. For example :

```
      private static final String TAG_Clicked = "TagClicked";
      private int counter = 0;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_term_signup);

        CheckBox checkBoxTOS = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_termsOfService);
        CheckBox checkBoxPNP = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_privacy_policy);
        Button buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

        checkBoxTOS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
              counter++;
              checkBoxTOS.isChecked();
              Log.d(TAG_Clicked, "Agreed TOS " + isChecked);
            } else {
              counter--
            }
            manageButtonState(counter);
          }
        });
        checkBoxPNP.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
              counter++;
              checkBoxPNP.isChecked();
              Log.d(TAG_Clicked, "Agreed PNP " + isChecked);
            } else {
              counter--;
            }
            manageButtonState(counter);

          }
        });

      }

      private void manageButtonState(int counter) {
        buttonNext.setEnabled(counter > 1)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    checkBoxTOS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked && checkBoxPNP.isChecked()){
           buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
            Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"Agreed TOS "+isChecked);
        }
        else
           buttonNext.setEnabled(true);
    }
});


checkBoxPNP.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked && checkBoxTOS.isChecked()){
            Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"Agreed PNP "+isChecked);
            buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
            buttonNext.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  checkBoxTOS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         //will called when you select or deselect
            enableOrDisableButton();
        }
    });
    checkBoxPNP.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {                
       //will called when you select or deselect
            enableOrDisableButton();
        }
    });

public void enableOrDisableButton(){
    if ((checkBoxTOS.isChecked() == true) && (checkBoxPNP.isChecked() == true)){
        buttonNext.setEnabled(true);
        Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"A");
    } else {
        buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
        Log.d(TAG_Clicked,"B");
    }}
```